# Подскажите структуру каталога для приложения php js css html?

Tags: php, javascript, структуры, хранение-данных, backend

Всем привет!
Система - классический LAMP
Подойдёт ли такая структура:
I. Общая папка проекта по адресу: /var/www/project:
в ней: 
____папка с js
____папка с php
____с html
____c css
Или это неправильно с точки зрения безопасности?
Проект - детская игра, скорее всего никто взламывать не будет, но хотелось бы как правильно)))
Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

1. Используешь ли ты какой-нибудь шаблон проектирования? Если да, то структуру такого проекта можно найти в интернете(советую MVC).
2. Я обычно создаю в таком виде.

> ---|Public - тут все, что доступно по сути пользователю.
>
> ------|Assets - js, css, fonts.
>
> ---------|js
>
> ---------|css
>
> ---------|fonts
>
> ------|views - вьюшки откуда подключаю файлы. html странички можно подключать тут же.
>
> ---|Core - программная часть. Классы, модели и подобное.
>
> -----|Classes
>
> ---|Configs - файлы конфигурации.
>
> index.php - в корне. Все запросы сюда.

Можно без знаний .htaccess и сложных паттернов проектирования делать простенький роутинг через $_GET параметры. Если нужен простой и быстрый проект, то Я его именно так и пишу. Могу скинуть репозиторий с примером, если интересно.

Comment: быстрый простой роутинг делается через микрофреймворк [silex](https://silex.symfony.com/), там же в комплекте идет шаблонизатор twig

Comment: @TotalPusher Silex - depracated. `Silex is in maintenance mode. Ends of life is set to June 2018. Use Symfony 4 instead.` - https://silex.symfony.com/doc/2.0/changelog.html , https://symfony.com/blog/the-end-of-silex

Comment: @jashka Жаль, мне он понравился

Comment: Да! Давай! iesbk@bk.ru. Буду очень благодарен!

Comment: Нет, не использую шаблоны (, пока читаю большую четверку как это правильно делать

Answer (score 2):

Я писал один раз фреймворк и сделал такую структуру

Что по поводу организации безопасности, то у тебя код приложения должен быть за рамками входного файла что бы `умелый человек` не смог прямые Ссылки на исходник знать
Входной файл `public/index.php`, код `src/`
`src` и `public` на одном уровне

Больше `symfony way` но может почерпнете что-то себе

```
├── app
│   ├── config
│   └── logs
├── Framework
│   ├── Config
│   ├── Controller
│   ├── Database
│   ├── DI
│   ├── Event
│   ├── Exception
│   ├── Helper
│   ├── Logger
│   ├── Model
│   ├── Patterns
│   ├── Renderer
│   ├── Request
│   ├── Response
│   ├── Router
│   ├── Security
│   ├── Services
│   ├── Session
│   └── Validation
│       └── Filter
├── src
│   ├── CMS
│   │   ├── config
│   │   ├── Controller
│   │   ├── Migrations
│   │   ├── Model
│   │   └── views
│   └── Shop
│       ├── config
│       ├── Controller
│       ├── Model
│       ├── Services
│       └── views
├── storage
│   └── session
└── web
    ├── css
    ├── fonts
    ├── images
    │   └── uploads
    ├── js
    └── uploads
```

Comment: Получается - это MVC? То есть всё общение с сайтом будет происходить через входной файл и файлы-представления в папке views?

Comment: @O.O да это MVC, да, но у вас могут папки могут быть по другому, но точка входа одна